# Convert TimeZone offset to TimeZone text

Tags: datetime, jodatime, java-6

I have a string in format "2019-04-25T16:34:28-05:00". I have parsed the string by joda-time by pattern "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ".

```
DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(formatStr);
DateTime temp = df.parseDateTime(dateStr);
```

And it giving me the output in DateTime as "2019-04-25T15:34:28.000-06:00".

Until this all seems correct but I am wanting the output with TimeZone text like "04-25-2019 03:34 PM CDT".

I am formatting the DateTime object by:

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM-dd-yyyy 
hh:mm a z");
```

but I am getting -06:00 still the output as "04-25-2019 03:34 PM -06:00".

How can I get the timezone name like "CDT" in place of offset?

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get the timezone name like "CDT" in place of offset?

You can't.  `-05:00` might be `CDT`, but it is also an offset that could apply to a large number of other time zones.  For example, `EST` in the US, or perhaps `ACT` in Brazil or `PET` in Peru, or many others...

Even if you were to limit this problem to US time zones, consider that `MST` and `PDT` are both UTC-7, though `MST` applies year-round in most of Arizona while `PDT` only applies during daylight saving time in the Pacific time zone.  If you are given a timestamp in the summer with a `-07:00` offset, it is impossible to tell which it belongs to, even constrained to the US.

In other words, in order to know which abbreviation to use, you must provide a time zone identifier (such as `America/Los_Angeles`), not just an offset.

See also "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: So is there any idea how can I achieve date as "04-25-2019 04:34 PM CDT" from String "2019-04-25T16:34:28-05:00" in Java 6?

Comment: You would have to supply the actual time zone identifier.  For example `formatter.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Chicago"))`.  If you don't already know the time zone in advance, then you're out of luck because it cannot be inferred from the offset alone.

Comment: Is there any way that the given string with the offset given can parsed in UTC time?